# Pausing game when app goes inactive - stopping timers issue

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

So I have a game that uses different timers. These timers provide crucial gameplay features, so it is imerative that they work as intended.
When an app goes to inactive state I can use

```
scene.paused = true
```

This pauses all action but timers. I have to invalidate every timer myself. Then when app goes active I need to create all these timers again. Unfortunately this breaks designed flow of the game. For example my timer is firing an event every 5 seconds. App goes inactive when a timer should fire an event in 1 second. If I invalidate it and then create again this timer will fire an event in 5 seconds.
Yes I can keep track of current time for every timer, but It seems to be a lot of trouble (I have A LOT of different SKScenes with different timers)

This is unacceptable, so I am looking for a better solution. First thing that comes to mind is to use SKAction.waitForDuration instead of timers.
So I want your advice if it is a good solution. Can I get correctly paused SKActions this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it was a good idea after all. Migrating to SKAction made pausing easy.